# File Mime Type to Human Readable Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mime-types

I am writing a system in Ruby on Rails 4 that is a type of file repository that is used to store various files.  Each file will have its own description page that will display information about it.  One thing that is required is to display a human readable file type.  Thus for a `.jpeg` file, it should display something along the lines of `Image` or `JPEG Image`.  And for `.doc` / `.docx` it should say `Microsoft Office Word Document`.

Any thoughts or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

See my gem for that: https://github.com/lukaszsliwa/friendly_mime

```
# Gemfile
gem 'friendly_mime'

# config/initializers/friendly_mime.rb
require 'friendly_mime'
Friendly::MIME.load

# rails console
> Friendly::MIME.find 'application/zip'
=> "Zip Archive"
> Friendly::MIME.find '.zip'
=> "Zip Archive"
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to copy-paste a list of mime types and descriptions (like from here http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list) and then just create an array of it..

Comment: I looked for a list of mime-type to english name table for 30ish minutes and was unable to find it.  Thanks a lot for the link.  I'm not very fond of this solution, but i do feel that it might be the best thing to do.